# Remove seen notifications from Notification Centre

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey, alert

I am using MacOS Monterrey, and whenever I get notification from say, Slack, I get a temporary banner on my screen, which then hides in the notification tray. Then I open Slack (without using the Notification Centre), check the new message, but the notification stays in the Notification Centre as if I had never opened it. This is very annoying as at the end of the day my notification centre is full of banners about events I have already checked.

Is there a way to automatically remove notifications from the Notification Centre when I have already checked them in the app? This is standard behaviour in things like Android.

Thanks!

(PS I am very new to MacOS)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a way to do this in Mac OS X.