# Make Slack notification banners go away when the message is read

Tags: notifications, slack

Is there a way to make Slack notification banners disappear automatically when I've read the new message?

When I get a Slack message, a banner pops up on the screen.  When I have read the message in the Slack app, I still have to click the banner to make it go away.  I would like it to go away on its own when the message has been read.

Also, see [Remove seen notifications from Notification Centre](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/442205/remove-seen-notifications-from-notification-centre).

Comment: what banner, what does it says

Comment: change Notification to 'banners' from 'alert'

Comment: Maybe it's better known as a toast notification?  It's at the top right of the screen, similar to the alert from the Calendar or Reminder app.  It contains the name of the sender and the first few words of the message.